# Vs code .value is not recognized by intellisense

Tags: javascript, html, input, intellisense

I am very new to javascript, but as I was working I was trying to figure out a way to get the text a user would input into an html input text box, but for some reason vs code does not recognize the intellisense required to do this.

My HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="first-input">
    <button id="submit-button">Submit</button>
    <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: HTML]

The JavaScript:

```
let firstInput = document.getElementById('first-input');
let submitButton = document.getElementById('submit-button');

submitButton.onclick = function () {
    console.log(firstInput.value);
}
```

[image: JavaScript]

In order to get the data inside an input text element, the code for that is .value, however when i start typing ".val-" the only recommendation VS code has is for .nodeValue.

[image: no .value option, only .nodeValue]

This means, in order to get what I want, I am using a command that the intellisense for vs code doesn't recognize. However, even though intellisense does not find it, the code still operates as intended.

[image: code is functional]

Is there something I need to install or do to get access to this information? I am concerned there are many other things it doesn't recognize and will make learning this language more difficult. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `getElementById()` doesn't necessarily return an element with a `.value` property.  For example, it could return a `<div>` element.

In order for the intellisense to know that you will have a `.value` property, you have to indicate with a JSDoc comment that the variable `firstInput` is going to be an `<input>` element.  Like this:

```
/**
 * @type HTMLInputElement
 */
let firstInput = document.getElementById('first-input');
/**
 * @type HTMLButtonElement
 */
let submitButton = document.getElementById('submit-button');

submitButton.onclick = function () {
  console.log(firstInput.value);
}
```

Not to confuse you, but VSCode uses TypeScript to power its intellisense, [even for JavaScript code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html).