# How to access input (text) elements inside a form, put them in an array and access their value using a loop?

Tags: javascript, html

Note; I am new to JavaScript.  The intention of the program is to sort inputted values of numbers using different algorithms, which the user chooses.  It has to be done this way since this is how our lecturer gave us the coursework.

I would like to get the values of inputs inside a table, inside a form element, but for some reason I can't access the values of the inputs.

I've tried accessing elements by Id, class, tag, etc using document.getElementById in my javascript file like;

```js
for (let i = 1; i <=  20; i++){
        myArray[i] = document.getElementById(`input${i}`).value
    }
```

and

```js
myArray.forEach(function(element){
        document.write(element);
    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="mainStyling.css">
        <script src="mainFunctionality.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <header>
        <h1>CIS1103 Assignment 1 - Sorting Algorithms</h1>
    </header>
    <body>
        <section class="inputs" id="inputSection">
            <form onsubmit="determineWhichButton()">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number 1: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input1"</td>
                        <td>Number 11: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input11"</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number 2: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input2"</td>
                        <td>Number 12: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input12"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number 3: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input3"></td>
                        <td>Number 13: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input13"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number 4: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input4"></td>
                        <td>Number 14: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input14"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number 5: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input5"></td>
                        <td>Number 15: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input15"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number 6: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input6"></td>
                        <td>Number 16: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input16"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number 7: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input7"></td>
                        <td>Number 17: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input17"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number 8: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input8"></td>
                        <td>Number 18: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input18"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number 9: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input9"></td>
                        <td>Number 19: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input19"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number 10: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input10"></td>
                        <td>Number 20: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input20"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <hr>
                <div class="inputs" id="buttonSection">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Bubble" onclick="determineWhichButton('bubble')">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Quick" onclick="determineWhichButton('quick')">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Insertion" onclick="determineWhichButton('insertion')">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Shell" onclick="determineWhichButton('shell')">
                </div>
            </form>
        </section>
        <hr>
        <section class="inputs" id="displaySection">
            <p class="inputs" id="algoDisplay">
                Algorithm steps go here;
            </p>
        </section>
        <hr>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First 2 rows have open input tags, could it be it?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all input values:

```
const allInputValues = [...document.querySelectorAll('.inputs')].map(x => x.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just not writing your HTML correctly

> Missing closing for inputs '`>`'

```
<td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input1"</td>
```

change it with

```
<td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input1" ></td>
```

And so on

You need to complete your homework now  here's a simple start:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="mainStyling.css">
        <script src="mainFunctionality.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <header>
        <h1>CIS1103 Assignment 1 - Sorting Algorithms</h1>
    </header>
    <body>
        <section class="inputs" id="inputSection">
            <form onsubmit="determineWhichButton()">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number 1: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input1"></td>
                        <td>Number 11: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input11"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number 2: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input2"></td>
                        <td>Number 12: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input12"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number 3: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input3"></td>
                        <td>Number 13: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input13"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number 4: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input4"></td>
                        <td>Number 14: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input14"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number 5: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input5"></td>
                        <td>Number 15: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input15"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number 6: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input6"></td>
                        <td>Number 16: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input16"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number 7: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input7"></td>
                        <td>Number 17: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input17"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number 8: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input8"></td>
                        <td>Number 18: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input18"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number 9: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input9"></td>
                        <td>Number 19: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input19"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number 10: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input10"></td>
                        <td>Number 20: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputs" id="input20"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <hr>
                <div class="inputs" id="buttonSection">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Bubble" onclick="determineWhichButton('bubble')">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Quick" onclick="determineWhichButton('quick')">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Insertion" onclick="determineWhichButton('insertion')">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Shell" onclick="determineWhichButton('shell')">
                </div>
            </form>
        </section>
        <hr>
        <section class="inputs" id="displaySection">
            <p class="inputs" id="algoDisplay">
                Algorithm steps go here;
            </p>
        </section>
        <hr>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    function determineWhichButton(algorithm){
      if(algorithm === 'bubble'){
        console.log('inside bubble')
          var myArray = [];
for (let i = 1; i <=  20; i++){
        myArray[i] = document.getElementById(`input${i}`).value
        console.log('input : '+ document.getElementById(`input${i}`).value)
    }
      }
    }

    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: The missing > is because I mistakenly edited the code when I entered it into StackOverflow, but thanks for your input!  I'll try this out when I get home.

Comment: My problem is this: when I write myArray[i] = document.getElementById(`input1${i}`) Visual Studio Code doesn't give me the suggestion .value and if I write .value, it doesn't work.  Im completely stuck on this.

Comment: You will never see the 'Value' suggestion in because VSCode uses TypeScript to power its intellisense look at this  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html

Comment: Here's an answer for this =>  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55271251/vs-code-value-is-not-recognized-by-intellisense