# Alert box not displaying Sum with Html Input Fields

Tags: javascript, html, input, alert, html-input

New to website programming. I'm trying to make a basic sum equation with 2 input fields taken from client-side.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="number" id="x">
            <input type="number" id="y">
        <script>
            let x = document.getElementById('x').nodeValue;
            let y = document.getElementById('y').nodeValue;

            function sum(x, y) {
                let sum = x + y;
                alert(sum);
            }
        </script>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="sum(x, y)">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I run my code in a browser(Opera Gx if that matters) and when I choose two numbers, then hit submit, it shows the alertbox. What shows up however is:

"[object HTMLInputElement][object HTMLInputElement]"

I know that the input elements are being used, but I obviously want my sum function to return a sum of the 2 input fields.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code is related to how you're retrieving the values of the input fields. You're using the `nodeValue` property, which is not the correct way to get the values of input elements. For what `nodeValue` returns check out [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue).

Instead, you should use the `value` property to retrieve the values of input elements. Here's the corrected code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sum Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="number" id="x">
        <input type="number" id="y">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="sum()">
    </form>

    <script>
        function sum() {
            // Retrieve the values of the input fields and try to parse them
            let x = parseFloat(document.getElementById('x').value);
            let y = parseFloat(document.getElementById('y').value);

            // Check if the input values are valid numbers
            if (!isNaN(x) && !isNaN(y)) {
                // Perform the sum
                let result = x + y;
                alert("The sum is: " + result);
            } else {
                alert("Please enter valid numbers in both fields.");
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

I don't understand what parseFloat is? and is it necessary?

Is checking if input values are valid numbers necessary or is it just best practice?

Why was result able to show up in alert as a value instead of sum?

Comment: Here `parseFloat` is converting value from input field to number. Check out docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat. Is it necessary? Well, it depends on your needs. Since `.value` returns string even though input type is number, it is logical that you have to convert string to number so that you can continue working with it as number (to do sum for example). Checking if it valid number is good practice. It might not be necessary but it's good. Don't really understand last question.

Comment: Oh, didn't know the value of the input field is immediately a string. Good to know parseFloat changes that. The last question was asking why my sum variable returned the "[Object HtmlInputElement]" and your result variable was able to. Now that I understand what parseFloat does, I think it was because the inital values were just strings instead of numbers.

Comment: `alert` function is trying to convert what's passed to it to string. If you pass string or number to it, it will work fine since it's easy to imagine how it would convert it to string, right? But `nodeValue` can return some kind of object. If you pass it to `alert` function it will try to convert that object to string which isn't that straightforward right? What you got (`"[Object HtmlInputElement]"`) was result of that conversion. I would suggest that you check out docs for functions you are trying to call and properties you try to use.

Comment: Thank you! This really has helped me out! -and now I finally got involved with Stack after a while of trying to avoid it lol. Preciate you.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the values of your inputs fields when the function is being called (and not once when the script is running like you have now, because you will get the wrong value).

To do so you can use the `.value` property instead of using the `nodeValue` on the elements like this:

```html
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="number" id="x">
        <input type="number" id="y">
    <script>
        let x = document.getElementById('x');
        let y = document.getElementById('y');

        function sum(x, y) {
            let sum = x.value + y.value;
            alert(sum);
        }
    </script>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="sum(x, y)">
</form>
</body>
```

This way `x` and `y` are referring to the elements and you can extract the values when you want to.

NOTICE - This will give you the wrong result, and this is because `.value` will return a string.
You will also need to parse the values into numbers while summing:

```html
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="number" id="x">
        <input type="number" id="y">
    <script>
        let x = document.getElementById('x');
        let y = document.getElementById('y');

        function sum(x, y) {
            let sum = parseFloat(x.value) + parseFloat(y.value);
            alert(sum);
        }
    </script>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="sum(x, y)">
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: For some reason, "value" doesn't show up in autotab in vscode https://imgur.com/a/0DG2Ynx This is why I went with nodeValue. Do you know how to get it to show up? or if it would work without autotab functionality?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55271251/vs-code-value-is-not-recognized-by-intellisense)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Good to know .value still works even if it's not listed.

Answer (score 1):

You also don't need to add parameters in your function

```html
<form>
    <input type="number" id="x"/>
    <input type="number" id="y"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="sum()">
    <script>
        function sum() {
            let x = parseFloat(document.getElementById('x').value)
            let y = parseFloat(document.getElementById('y').value)
            let theSum = x + y;
            alert(theSum)
        }
    </script>
</form>
```

Comment: Is it because I defined and declared x and y in the global scope before the function?

Comment: if you keep your let x and let y outside of the function the value will be NaN. You should get the value of x and y when you call the function onclick after filling the input (and not when the code runs with no input value: NaN). Try giving a value to your inputs (value"3" and value="6") and you will see and understand what I mean.

Comment: Tested it out and what you said is true. I just don't get why x and y can't be defined in global scope and not work within the function. Why does it work when x and y are defined in the local scope of the function?

Comment: Here it is not really a question of local scope and global scope. if you keep let x and let y outside of the function x and y are read when the code runs and when there is no value in inputs so value is NaN. You should get the value x and y when you fill the input so when you click the submit button and call the sum function you get the values in input. Hope my english explanation is clear  ..And this is very important to understand in javascript

Comment: If this explanation helped you, you can upvote 

Comment: Trust me, I've been trying. Still waiting on 15 rep 

Comment: Loool  I forgot about that, Hope you got it now 

Comment: I do, thanks! Preciate all the help.

Comment: You very welcome. Pls feel free to ask for any help if we can